# How to remove event listener of a object with .bind(this)?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Inside object constructor:

```
this.notification.addEventListener(barcodeScanner.NEW_READING, this.handleBarcode.bind(this));
```

And when it destroys:

```
this.notification.removeEventListener(barcodeScanner.NEW_READING, this.handleBarcode.bind(this), this);
```

I can add event listener and works properly but I cannot remove single event listener when object destroys.

Although it is not quite related to the problem, I am using EventDispatcher.js and Class.js.

I can modify code in EventDispatcher.js to fit what I need. But how can I remove event listener of a object's function without removing all other listener?

Answer (score 11):

It's not being removed because it's a *different* object.

`.bind()` returns a new object every time.

You need to store it somewhere and use it to remove:

```
var handler = this.handleBarcode.bind(this);
```

then

```
this.notification.addEventListener(barcodeScanner.NEW_READING, handler);
```

or

```
this.notification.removeEventListener(barcodeScanner.NEW_READING, handler);
```

Comment: I store the handler in object attribute but I still cannot remove it successfully

Comment: @aokaddaoc: please provide some details for "I store the handler in object attribute"

Comment: if i have to send paremeters using the handler, how can I? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way how to **bind** and **unbind** **event** handler **in** some **component**:

```
var o = {
  list: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  add: function () {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    b.addEventListener('click', this._onClick());

  },
  remove: function () {
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    b.removeEventListener('click', this._onClick());
  },
  _onClick: function () {
    this.clickFn = this.clickFn || this._showLog.bind(this);
    return this.clickFn;
  },
  _showLog: function (e) {
    console.log('click', this.list, e);
  }
};



// Example to test the solution

o.add();

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('setTimeout');
  o.remove();
}, 5000);
```